# Appium with C#. Issue with Appium don net driver (Version 1.3.0.1). The AppiumDriver in the dll is coming with generics

Tags: c#, android, appium

I am developing mobile automation using C# and Appium. When I try to instantiate the AppiumDriver it is asking me to Add generics of type IWebElement like AppiumDriver.

But all of the sample examples all over the internet are having AppiumDriver Instantiated without the generic.

Please help me with this as i am stuck with this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium; 
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Android;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DesiredCapabilities Usercapabilities;

            Usercapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            Usercapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "Nexus 7");
            Usercapabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Android");

            Usercapabilities.SetCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
            Usercapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
         //using the Appium_dot_net_driver (version 1.3.0.1) 
            AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), Usercapabilities); //Initialise appium which throwing some error saying to add <IWebelement>
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://jobs.adp.com"); //launch URL
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12));
            By txt_keywordSearch = By.Name("k");
            By btn_Search = By.XPath("//button[contains(@id,'search-submit')]");
            By section_Searchresults = By.Id("search-results");
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@data-callout-action,'job matching')]")).Click();
            if (driver.FindElement(txt_keywordSearch).Displayed)
            {
                driver.FindElement(txt_keywordSearch).SendKeys("Manager");
                driver.FindElement(btn_Search).Click();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
                if (driver.FindElement(section_Searchresults).Displayed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("successfully Navigated to search results page");
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("Did not Navigate to search results page");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont care about your question because it is in not my competence. But without a code in any language it is a problem to answer for anyone. See stackoverflow FAQ. Also, if you are operating with code entities you should provide the code too.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change this:

```cs
AppiumDriver driver = new AppiumDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), Usercapabilities);
```

for this:

```
AppiumDriver<IWebElement> driver = new AppiumDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), Usercapabilities);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Appium version 1.53.0, the `AppiumDriver` has been made abstract.
You have to user `IOSDriver` or `AndroidDriver` like this:

```
new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(...)
```